# Representation of a polynomial in several variables as a product of linear polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I am interested in such a question.

What are necessary and sufficient conditions for representation of an algebraic polynomial in several variables with real coefficients in the form of the product of linear polynomials?

For example, let us that we have a polynomial in three variables $P(x,y,z)$.

I mean the following its representation:
$$
P(x,y,z)=(a_{1}+b_{1}x+c_{1}y+d_{1}z)(a_{2}+b_{2}x+c_{2}y+d_{2}z)\ldots (a_{m}+b_{m}x+c_{m}y+d_{m}z).
$$

I will be grateful for any help, for any references.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!!

Comment: The conditions should be directly correlated with those conditions required for single-variable-polynomials; I would start by treating all but one variable as constant, then solving the problem in that one variable, then repeating the process for the rest of the variables.

Comment: Well, have you tried to do it for a very simple example like $y-x^2$ or $x^2+y^2-1$? My doubt arises from the geometric fact that when $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, then the equation $fg=0$ has for its zero-set the union (with overlaps of usually smaller dimension) of the two sets defined by the equations $f=0$ and $g=0$. One expects that when an algebraic set in the plane is not the union of two proper subsets of the same dimension, then the defining polynomial for the original set is more or less irreducible.